# Why does android Room need an internet connection to store data

Tags: android, android-room

From this site: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room

".. The most common use case is to cache relevant pieces of data. That way, when **the device cannot access the network**, the user can still browse that content while they are offline. Any user-initiated content changes are then synced to the server after the device is back online."

Why is rooming trying to **access the network**, when the data is stored locally as Room is a local database?

That description seems wrong or do I misunderstand something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Room doesn't require network access.

That is just giving an example of a situation where SQLite (and therefore Room) can be useful as SQlite is an embedded database. That is if the App gets data via the network but the device may not always have access then some data can be stored locally on the device freeing it from permenant newtwork access.

It is quite feasible to have Apps that use Room that have no network access at all. In which case the data would either be input by the device's user or perhaps distributed via the APK.